# how can i group hours range with an array javascript?

Tags: javascript

How can I group the range of hours and their quantity with a JavaScript array

i have this

example:

```
['2019-09-12 13:45:24', '2019-09-12 13:00:00', '2019-09-12 12:30:00', '2019-09-12 11:45:00']
```

I want this :

```
[{
 hours: '11:00 to 12:00',
 quantity: 1
},
{
 hours: '12:00 to 13:00',
 quantity: 1
},
{
 hours: '13:00 to 14:00',
 quantity: 2
}]
```

Comment: Hi, could you add what you've tried so far ?

Comment: Hi Nicolas, thanks for answering. I don't have a possible solution

Comment: @JohanStivenHernandezOsorio do you have any incomplete efforts? Or have you not tried?

Comment: I do not understand why they closed the question, what I was looking for was a way to solve a problem presented since the possible solutions were not successful.

Although I already found a solution to my question I want to make my contribution, maybe someone will serve at some point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    let array = ['2019-09-12 13:45:24', '2019-09-12 13:00:00', '2019-09-12 12:30:00', '2019-09-12 11:45:00'];
    let result = [];

    for (let i = 0, l = array.length; i < l; i++) {
      let h = (new Date(array[i])).getHours();

      let item = result.filter(x => x.hours.startsWith(h + ':'));
      item = item.length ? item[0] : null;

      if (item) {
        item.quantity +=1;
      } else {
        item = {
          hours: h + ':00 to ' + (h + 1 === 24 ? '0' : h + 1) + ':00',
          quantity: 1
        }

        result.push(item);
      }
    }

    console.log(result);
```

Comment: Hi assembler this works, Thanks